# MySQL min function in where clause, how does it works?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select
    s_acctbal, s_name, n_name, p_partkey, p_mfgr, 
    s_address, s_phone, s_comment
from 
    part, supplier, partsupp, nation, region
where 
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
    and p_size = 15
    and p_type like '%BRASS'
    and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
    and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
    and r_name = 'EUROPE'
    and ps_supplycost = (
        select 
            min(ps_supplycost)
        from 
            partsupp, supplier, nation, region
        where 
            p_partkey = ps_partkey
            and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
            and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
            and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
            and r_name = 'EUROPE'
    )
order by 
    s_acctbal desc, n_name, s_name, p_partkey;
```

**First doubt:**

Why in the subselect (the inner select) `r_name='EUROPE'` was set again? I understand that the line `p_partkey = ps_partkey` give to this subselect the same conditions of the outter select, so there is no need to set it again, or not?

**Second doubt:**

The line `r_name = 'EUROPE'` in the inner select make some diferences (that i cant see, but i want to know) in the query. If i count the results of the original query i had 460 entrys. And if i get out the  `r_name = 'EUROPE'` of inner select i got only 144 entrys.
This look like crazy, with this condition (and consequently more restrictions) and had more results than when i get out the condition. Why this occurs?

FYI (maybe this help why my mind is blowing with this query):

The original query returns:

```
s_acctbal s_name             n_name         p_partkey p_mfgr         s_address                              s_phone         s_comment                                                                                      
--------- ------------------ -------------- --------- -------------- -------------------------------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
9938.53   Supplier#000005359 UNITED KINGDOM 185358    Manufacturer#4 QKuHYh,vZGiwu2FWEJoLDx04               33-429-790-6131 blithely silent pinto beans are furiously. slyly final deposits acros

9937.84   Supplier#000005969 ROMANIA        108438    Manufacturer#1 ANDENSOSmk,miq23Xfb5RWt6dvUcvt6Qa      29-520-692-3537 carefully slow deposits use furiously. slyly ironic platelets above the ironic 

9936.22   Supplier#000005250 UNITED KINGDOM 249       Manufacturer#4 B3rqp0xbSEim4Mpy2RH J                  33-320-228-2957 blithely special packages are. stealthily express deposits across the closely final instructi

9923.77   Supplier#000002324 GERMANY        29821     Manufacturer#4 y3OD9UywSTOk                           17-779-299-1839 quickly express packages breach quiet pinto beans. requ

9871.22   Supplier#000006373 GERMANY        43868     Manufacturer#5 J8fcXWsTqM                             17-813-485-8637 never silent deposits integrate furiously blit

9870.78   Supplier#000001286 GERMANY        81285     Manufacturer#2 YKA,E2fjiVd7eUrzp2Ef8j1QxGo2DFnosaTEH  17-516-924-4574 final theodolites cajole slyly special, 

9870.78   Supplier#000001286 GERMANY        181285    Manufacturer#4 YKA,E2fjiVd7eUrzp2Ef8j1QxGo2DFnosaTEH  17-516-924-4574 final theodolites cajole slyly special, 

9852.52   Supplier#000008973 RUSSIA         18972     Manufacturer#2 t5L67YdBYYH6o,Vz24jpDyQ9               32-188-594-7038 quickly regular instructions wake-- carefully unusual braids into the expres

9847.83   Supplier#000008097 RUSSIA         130557    Manufacturer#2 xMe97bpE69NzdwLoX                      32-375-640-3593 slyly regular dependencies sleep slyly furiously express dep

9847.57   Supplier#000006345 FRANCE         86344     Manufacturer#1 VSt3rzk3qG698u6ld8HhOByvrTcSTSvQlDQDag 16-886-766-7945 silent pinto beans should have to snooze carefully along the final reques

9847.57   Supplier#000006345 FRANCE         173827    Manufacturer#2 VSt3rzk3qG698u6ld8HhOByvrTcSTSvQlDQDag 16-886-766-7945 silent pinto beans should have to snooze carefully along the final reques
```

The query without the inner select condition `r_name = 'EUROPA'` returns:

```
s_acctbal s_name             n_name         p_partkey p_mfgr         s_address                               s_phone         s_comment                                                                             
--------- ------------------ -------------- --------- -------------- --------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
9938.53   Supplier#000005359 UNITED KINGDOM 185358    Manufacturer#4 QKuHYh,vZGiwu2FWEJoLDx04                33-429-790-6131 blithely silent pinto beans are furiously. slyly final deposits acros

9817.10   Supplier#000002352 RUSSIA         124815    Manufacturer#2 4LfoHUZjgjEbAKw TgdKcgOc4D4uCYw         32-551-831-1437 blithely pending packages across the ironic accounts grow slyly after the furiously

9721.95   Supplier#000008757 UNITED KINGDOM 156241    Manufacturer#3 Atg6GnM4dT2                             33-821-407-2995 ironic, even dolphins above the furiously ironic foxes sleep slyly around the caref

9643.55   Supplier#000005148 ROMANIA        107617    Manufacturer#1 kT4ciVFslx9z4s79p Js825                 29-252-617-4850 doggedly even ideas boost furiously against the furiously express

9612.94   Supplier#000003228 ROMANIA        198189    Manufacturer#4 KDdpNKN3cWu7ZSrbdqp7AfSLxx,qWB          29-325-784-8187 carefully pending accounts serve. furiously close deposits boost slyly. q

9571.83   Supplier#000004305 ROMANIA        179270    Manufacturer#2 qNHZ7WmCzygwMPRDO9Ps                    29-973-481-1831 furiously final deposits 

9558.10   Supplier#000003532 UNITED KINGDOM 88515     Manufacturer#4 EOeuiiOn21OVpTlGguufFDFsbN1p0lhpxHp     33-152-301-2164 daring, sly accounts breach about th

9280.27   Supplier#000007194 ROMANIA        47193     Manufacturer#3 zhRUQkBSrFYxIAXTfInj vyGRQjeK           29-318-454-2133 slyly ironic requests despite the unusual ins

9249.35   Supplier#000003973 FRANCE         26466     Manufacturer#1 d18GiDsL6Wm2IsGXM,RZf1jCsgZAOjNYVThTRP4 16-722-866-1658 quickly ironic sauternes use b

9249.35   Supplier#000003973 FRANCE         33972     Manufacturer#1 d18GiDsL6Wm2IsGXM,RZf1jCsgZAOjNYVThTRP4 16-722-866-1658 quickly ironic sauternes use b

9201.47   Supplier#000009690 UNITED KINGDOM 67183     Manufacturer#5 CB BnUTlmi5zdeEl7R7                     33-121-267-9529 blithely unusual accounts integrate slyly. platelets 

9094.57   Supplier#000004582 RUSSIA         39575     Manufacturer#1 WB0XkCSG3r,mnQ n,h9VIxjjr9ARHFvKgMDf    32-587-577-1351 asymptotes above the slyly even requests haggle furiously about the regular accounts
```

And last the query without (ps_supplycost = ...) returns:

```
s_acctbal s_name             n_name         p_partkey p_mfgr         s_address                              s_phone         s_comment                                                                                          
--------- ------------------ -------------- --------- -------------- -------------------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
9984.69   Supplier#000008875 ROMANIA        13872     Manufacturer#3 hRdOqKqyU,sHq                          29-132-904-4395 ironic instructions among the ironic requests boost at the ironic, ironic deposits. quick

9955.05   Supplier#000008810 UNITED KINGDOM 73795     Manufacturer#2 ,Ot93zDXOFSjWSKsKrT7XJ4YPCP,A          33-527-478-5988 furiously unusual pinto beans nag ironic platelets. regular, bold fox

9955.05   Supplier#000008810 UNITED KINGDOM 81285     Manufacturer#2 ,Ot93zDXOFSjWSKsKrT7XJ4YPCP,A          33-527-478-5988 furiously unusual pinto beans nag ironic platelets. regular, bold fox

9938.53   Supplier#000005359 UNITED KINGDOM 185358    Manufacturer#4 QKuHYh,vZGiwu2FWEJoLDx04               33-429-790-6131 blithely silent pinto beans are furiously. slyly final deposits acros

9937.84   Supplier#000005969 ROMANIA        108438    Manufacturer#1 ANDENSOSmk,miq23Xfb5RWt6dvUcvt6Qa      29-520-692-3537 carefully slow deposits use furiously. slyly ironic platelets above the ironic 

9936.22   Supplier#000005250 UNITED KINGDOM 249       Manufacturer#4 B3rqp0xbSEim4Mpy2RH J                  33-320-228-2957 blithely special packages are. stealthily express deposits across the closely final instructi

9923.77   Supplier#000002324 GERMANY        29821     Manufacturer#4 y3OD9UywSTOk                           17-779-299-1839 quickly express packages breach quiet pinto beans. requ

9871.22   Supplier#000006373 GERMANY        43868     Manufacturer#5 J8fcXWsTqM                             17-813-485-8637 never silent deposits integrate furiously blit

9870.78   Supplier#000001286 GERMANY        81285     Manufacturer#2 YKA,E2fjiVd7eUrzp2Ef8j1QxGo2DFnosaTEH  17-516-924-4574 final theodolites cajole slyly special, 

9870.78   Supplier#000001286 GERMANY        181285    Manufacturer#4 YKA,E2fjiVd7eUrzp2Ef8j1QxGo2DFnosaTEH  17-516-924-4574 final theodolites cajole slyly special, 

9852.52   Supplier#000008973 RUSSIA         18972     Manufacturer#2 t5L67YdBYYH6o,Vz24jpDyQ9               32-188-594-7038 quickly regular instructions wake-- carefully unusual braids into the expres

9847.83   Supplier#000008097 RUSSIA         130557    Manufacturer#2 xMe97bpE69NzdwLoX                      32-375-640-3593 slyly regular dependencies sleep slyly furiously express dep

9847.57   Supplier#000006345 FRANCE         66344     Manufacturer#4 VSt3rzk3qG698u6ld8HhOByvrTcSTSvQlDQDag 16-886-766-7945 silent pinto beans should have to snooze carefully along the final reques

9847.57   Supplier#000006345 FRANCE         86344     Manufacturer#1 VSt3rzk3qG698u6ld8HhOByvrTcSTSvQlDQDag 16-886-766-7945 silent pinto beans should have to snooze carefully along the final reques

9847.57   Supplier#000006345 FRANCE         173827    Manufacturer#2 VSt3rzk3qG698u6ld8HhOByvrTcSTSvQlDQDag 16-886-766-7945 silent pinto beans should have to snooze carefully along the final reques

9836.93   Supplier#000007342 RUSSIA         4841      Manufacturer#4 JOlK7C1,7xrEZSSOw                      32-399-414-5385 final accounts haggle. bold accounts are furiously dugouts. furiously silent asymptotes are slyly
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try individual output of query `select min(ps_supplycost) ... `? I suspect it is returning multiple rows instead of one due to where clause in it.

Comment: Try using aliases so that it knows precisely which tables to refer to, in case it's still referring to the table from the main query - i.e. `select min(p2.ps_supplycost) from partsupp p2, supplier s2, nation n2, region r2 where p2.p_partkey = s2.ps_partkey` etc

Comment: I AGREE with Mr Fuzzy... For readability, and for others who may help and not know your table structures, it is better to be explicit by writing your queries with alias.field references for all field columns querying and in your join/where conditions.  If you can please update your query would make better opportunity for myself or others to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find the least expensive supply cost for any item of p_size = 15 and p_type like '%BRASS'... Your SUBQUERY does not have this limit... so your primary query could have 100 products (via the like), but your SUBQUERY could have 50,000 entries because you are not restricting that down to the same criteria of only those supplies of p_size = 15 with same product type.

You PROBABLY need to have your inner query also include the p_type and GROUP BY that for the MIN() to be applied, then include that as basis of the join.  I've rewritten the query with best guestimation of your table/field relationships by the naming convention you have...

Also, notice my inner query is explicitly using alias.field name references.  Hopefully to not allow confusion with same field name / values of the outer query.  I may not be exact, but think I am close on principle of what you are looking for.

```
select
      s_acctbal, 
      s_name, 
      n_name, 
      p_partkey, 
      p_mfgr, 
      s_address, 
      s_phone, 
      s_comment,
      p_type,
      ps_supplycost
   from 
      part
         JOIN partsupp
            ON p_partkey = ps_partkey 
            JOIN supplier
               ON ps_suppkey = s_suppkey 
               JOIN nation
                  ON s_nationkey = n_nationkey 
                  JOIN region
                     ON n_regionkey = r_regionkey
                     AND r_name = 'EUROPE'

         JOIN ( SELECT 
                      P.p_type,
                      MIN( PS.ps_supplycost ) MinCost
                   from 
                      part P
                         JOIN partsupp PS
                            ON P.p_partkey = PS.ps_partkey
                            JOIN supplier S
                               ON PS.ps_suppkey = S.s_suppkey 
                               JOIN nation N
                                  ON S.s_nationkey = N.n_nationkey 
                                  JOIN region R
                                     ON N.n_regionkey = R.r_regionkey
                                     AND R.r_name = 'EUROPE' 
                   where 
                          P.p_size = 15
                      AND P.p_type like '%BRASS'
                   ) MinPerType
            ON p_type = MinPerType.p_type
            AND ps_supplycost = MinPerType.MinCost        
   where 
          p_size = 15
      AND p_type like '%BRASS'
   order by 
      s_acctbal desc, 
      n_name, 
      s_name, 
      p_partkey;
```

So, as you can see, the inner query to detect the minimum price is based on each "P_TYPE" value.  If dealing with brass items, from musical instruments, or brass metals for fabrication, plumbing, etc, each "type" could have a drastic price difference and you are looking for ex:

```
BRASS #1  (small thing) that supply cost range $1.50 - $2.15  vs
BRASS #83 (huge item) that supply cost range $42.00 - $48.50
```

You would never have a BRASS #83 ever be picked since it would never have anything near a $1.50 price tag cost.  However, you could have 10 suppliers of BRASS #1 at the $1.50 range, and 7 suppliers for the BRASS #83 item at $42.00, so your final query would return 17 records (per this example)